# How to use Eclipse Neon's Mylyn with Jira since connector was discontinued

Tags: eclipse, jira, mylyn, eclipse-neon

After a [terrible decision](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/discontinuing-ide-connectors-support/) by Atlassian to discontinue the Eclipse Connector for Jira, it seems to me like there is no way to use Mylyn in Eclipse Neon to integrate with Jira. Is it just me? Are there any workarounds?

I tried installing Tasktop Dev Pro but it failed complaining about a jar not found in the Update Site. Besides, it doesn't seem like a proper solution since it brings *a lot* more than we need

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It definitively works with Eclipse Oxygen (still), using the Updatesite from atlassian, which is also mentioned on the [Bitbucket OpenSource project](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connector-eclipse). Please note, the [help page](http://atlassian-docs.bitbucket.org/IDEPLUGIN-ECLIPSE/Installing-the-Eclipse-Connector_159516375.html#InstallingtheEclipseConnector-sites%20help%20page), which is also hosted there, offers a download link to use the updatesite offline. Since the actual data there is in fact hosted by atlassian, let's just hope they don't drop support for hosting those files.

Update Site URL: http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7

I got the Version: `3.2.5.v20150427`

As far as I can see, the support is still fully functional, including the ability to create new tickets, add comments and manage ticket lifecycle

PS: I needed to configure the proxy settings accordingly (Jira is hosted in-house here, so we need an exception rule for the proxy used for internet connection by default).

Comment: hmmm. i don't get it. It worked this time. I can't be sure what I tried before but it would install and just not appear in the Task List view. Thank you

Comment: Verified as working in the current release of Neon.2 - didn't even have to disable the WikiText extension (but I have installed no other components on top of the base Java IDE pack - my editor at the moment is Atom, installed Eclipse *just* for Mylyn).

Comment: Whats the status with integrating JIRA with Mylyn in Eclipse Oxygen?

Comment: can confirm that. The same Plug-in version works in Eclipse Oxygen and with Jira v7.1.0

Comment: Working for me with Eclipse Neon 3 (4.6.3).

Comment: can confirm that the same (old) Plug-in version still works in Eclipse Photon 2018-09. So lets hope that Atlassian does not again starts to "improve" its tooling

Answer (score 1):

I have not fought with Neon yet, but in Mars which is also not officially supported, I was able to get Jira partly working using this install URL:

Atlassian Connector for Eclipse 3.7 and later - http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7

It allows me to see my task list, select Jiras and it will remember working sets for each Jira I select, but one important feature to me I cannot get to work is on the Team Synchronizing perspective I CANNOT add changed files to a change set tied to the Jira like I can in Luna.

I can see incoming changes by jira tied change sets, but not create out going jira tied change sets.

I have broken my Mars install many times trying to update Mylyn but if I take the 3.20 version it foo-bars my install.

Comment: It seems to work on Eclipse 2018-12 (at least in my environment).