# Use Jira Mylyn connector with Eclipse 2020-03?

Tags: eclipse, jira, mylyn

I was able to install the connector from http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7 as suggested in:

- [How to use Eclipse Neon's Mylyn with Jira since connector was discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39474207/1237617)
- [How To Install Atlassian Connector On Eclipse Photon 4.8.x Version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55916603/1237617)

Yet when I try to add a new repository it doesn't show Jira in there. 
[image]

Is there a way to still make it work, maybe by downgrading mylyn?

Answer (score 2):

I forked the Atlassian connector as well and updated it to work with the current Eclipse.
I just made some minor changes so that basic Jira Cloud support now works

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jiraconnector

George

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a fork here:
https://github.com/rastaman/jira-mylyn-connector

> **Context**
>
> This is a fork of the probably discontinued Atlassian IDE
> Connector for Eclipse which work on Eclipse 4.8. It has been tested
> with MacOS and Linux and as Java code it should work everywhere.
>
> **Target JIRA platforms**
>
> The connector has been lightly tested with JIRA
> 6.3.1 on-premise and Atlassian Cloud.

With a single release in 2018 labelled:

```
eclipse-connector-3.2.5.201808261123.zip
```

I've not tried it yet as my setup using [the details on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41702032/184325) to get the last release from Atlassian, and Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0), was working with JIRA on premises.

However we've recently migrated to JIRA Cloud and although it connects I now get this error trying to synchronise task lists:

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json.jsonexception jsonobject["name"] not found
```

I assume this is some mismatch between fields in the connector and Jira Cloud so I'll report back here once I've had time to try the forked connector.

Comment: The mismatch is because JIRA has removed the Name field from their User responses, insteading requesting people to use the userID field if they need a unique identifier, and the DisplayName if they want to show a human readable name.